# Convert Postman to C # code I attached two pictures of the Postman

Tags: c#, .net

How can I convert this into c# code?
by HttpClient

Please help to modify the code
Get a mistake when executing the code
I attached two pictures of the Postman

[image]
[image]

```
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
        (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            dict.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            dict.Add("username", username);
            dict.Add("password", password);
            dict.Add("grant_type", "password");
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, $"https://localhost:8443/rm/token");
            request.Headers.Add("user-agent", useragent);
            request.Headers.Add("deviceid", device_id);
            try
            {
                using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request).Result)
                {
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                        {
                            var json = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                            var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Login.response>(json);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

I adjusted question
Thank you all

Comment: Thank you, sir, for your reply Yes, I have tried I have modified the question and added some code

Comment: What exception is being thrown, and on which line?

Comment: {StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Pragma: no-cache
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Date: Fri, 03 Jul 2020 14:31:41 GMT
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Content-Length: 34
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
  Expires: -1
}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define a dictionary of values you want to post as content, but then don't do anything with it. You need to specify the [Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httprequestmessage.content?view=netcore-3.1#System_Net_Http_HttpRequestMessage_Content) property when creating the `HttpRequestMessage`.

For example:

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, $"https://localhost:8443/rm/token") { Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(dict) };
```